# Ionicon - Different Sizes, Same CSS

Tags: html, css, ionicons

*Disclaimer, I'm new to web devevelopment.*

I'm building a webpage that will use larger icons at the top of the page, and smaller icons lower down (ionicon v5). I've defined the class already for how I want the larger icons to appear but of-course now I wish to include smaller icons down the bottom, they're inheriting the class.

How do you define a separate class for this second set of icons to not inherit the first?

HTML & CSS for top icons:

```
<ion-icon name="time-outline"></ion-icon> 

ion-icon {
        color: #e67e22;
        display: block;
        font-size: 200%;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

I imagine this is simple for some of you, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show pls how you display big and small icons in html.

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding a class to the ion–icon element?
for example, you can have `<ion-icon class="icon–big" name="time-outline"></ion-icon>`

and then in your styles:

```
ion-icon {
    color: #e67e22;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.icon–big {
   font-size: 200%;
}
```

If it does not work try applying the class to a wrapper element